# how to retrive data using hashtable from database file

Tags: android, hashtable

I have problem in App lock project, i m performing all blocked app display in log-cat, but the value of block app are shows null using following code, i want to display all block app in output screen

```
for(int j =0; j<channel.size(); j++) {
    String s = (String) channel.get(j);
    Log.d("s", "block apps >> " + s);   
}
```

Comment: Try to explain your question more detailedly. no one know what you mean now.

Comment: i solved that problem, thank u for reply, now i have another problem, i want to retrieve all user install application from android phone, but using my code i got all application such as user installed & Adroid operating system apps (services), i want filter all user installed application from system application such as TTS Service, VPN service